# How to project face of object to plane?

Tags: math, three.js, transformation

I have implementing a "select face of an object and align it to plane" feature. How can I make selected face of object to  be parralel to plane?

I have already raycasting to object with mouse click, selecting faces. I have intersects.faces. I do tried to project these vectors of plane normal (which is (0,0,1)) but no luck. I'm trying to calculate quaternions with setFromUnitVectors but thats not working properly.

```
var face = intersects[0].face;
var obj = intersects[0].object;
var geom = obj.geometry;
var newGeo = new Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( geom );

var vertA = newGeo.vertices[face.a];
var vertB = newGeo.vertices[face.b];
var vertC = newGeo.vertices[face.c];

let projectedVertA = vertA.clone().projectOnPlane(window.planeGround.position.normalize());
let projectedVertB = vertB.clone().projectOnPlane(window.planeGround.position.normalize());
let projectedVertC = vertC.clone().projectOnPlane(window.planeGround.position.normalize());

var quaternion = new Quaternion();
quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(vertA.clone().normalize(), projectedVertA);
obj.applyQuaternion(quaternion);
quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(vertB.clone().normalize(), projectedVertB);
obj.applyQuaternion(quaternion);
quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(vertC.clone().normalize(), projectedVertC);
obj.applyQuaternion(quaternion);

newGeo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
let newBufferGeo = new BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( newGeo );
obj.geometry = newBufferGeo;
```

I'm expecting the object will rotate to be selected face will be parallel to plane. But its not working properly.

Comment: `quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(face.normal, planeNormal);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not deal with the positions but with the normals. The single quaternion you want is:

```
quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(faceNormal, planeNormal);
```

I assume you know the plane normal. Maybe even the face normal. If you don't have this, you can calculate it from (pseudo code, not three.js code):

```
faceNormal = normalize((vertB - vertA) x (vertC - vertA))
```